# print every substring of a string using for loop and not string methods

Tags: java

I want to store all the substrings of a string, for example: `"car"` => `{"c","a","r","ca","ar","car"}`.

I want to use a `for` loop in an array.The code below stores only `c`,`a`,`r` in the array.
Do I need a nested `for` loop to solve it?

```
String s = "car";
String[] arr;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    arr[i] = s.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: `"The code below stores only c,a,r in the array"` -- No it can't as this code should throw a NullPointerException when you try to assign anything to your null `arr` variable. Please show us your real code, the one where you initialize the `arr` variable.

Comment: what you're saying and what you provided don't match up! Please elaborate.

Comment: As for your algorithm, work it out on paper first -- work out how you'd go about deconstructing a small and a large word, and then the code should follow.

Comment: To specifically answer your question, "Do I need a nested for loop to solve it?" No, you do not. You could use nested while-loops or recursion, or some combination, but a nested for-loop is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ?

```
for(int c = 0 ; c < string.length ; c++ )
  {
     for(int i = 1 ; i <= string.length - c ; i++ )
     {
        String sub = string.substring(c, c+i);
        //do something with sub
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want this :

```
String s="car";

List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

for(int ch=0;ch<s.length();ch++){
    for(int pos=0;pos<s.length()-1;pos++)
    {               
        if(pos+ch+1<=s.length())
        {               
           list.add(s.substring(pos, pos+ch+1));
        } 
    }
}
System.out.println(""+list);
```